# Laravel - I want to Group By only two items in the query

Tags: laravel

I am running a select query in Laravel for count. But I only want to GroupBy only one field

I have written the query

```
$games = DB::table('game_point')
            ->select(
                'game_point.game_name',
                'game_point.point_assigned', 
                DB::raw("DATE(game_point.created_at) as created_at"), 
                DB::raw("COUNT(played_game.user_id) as total_users")
            )
            ->join("played_game","played_game.game","=","game_point.game_name")
            ->groupBy("played_game.game", "game_point.game_name")
            ->paginate(15);
```

I only want to groupby

```
game_point.game_name
```

and not all the selected fields. But there is error

Comment: What is the relation of the tables? One to many? I think you have to use distinct() instead of groupBy()

Comment: what error you are getting when you are executing this query?

Comment: game_point.point_assigned not in the Group Aggreagate